# What is the best play in two player Downfall?

Tags: untagged

[Downfall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downfall_(game)) (or [Downspin/"New Downfall"](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1099/downspin)) is a two player game published in 1970 with perfect information.*  The [rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/DownFall.PDF) are quite simple and generally we play with ten disks each in the normal order.

I am interested to know if anyone has already solved this game (or a variant of it) to find out which player should win and what the best set of moves is.

Also - do different editions have different wheel configurations?  From what I could find out they all had the same configuration.

* In practice, due to the design of the game then it can be hard to remember all the information.  Also note that some variants have a randomised starting position or four players.